# how to find empty row cell of the specific column using openpyxl

Tags: excel, row, openpyxl

I want to fill the data in the bolted box (column B, row 6).

[image]

My code only can find empty cell, B12

### Could you correct my code as below, using openpyxl (not using dataframe)

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
        
(omitted)
        
last_row = book_C3['Sheet1'].max_row + 1
for column, (key, value) in enumerate(new_data_fut.items(), start=2):
book_C3['Sheet1'].cell(row=last_row, column=column, value=value)
    
(omitted)
```

Comment: In Openpyxl 'max_row' is the last used row, i.e. the last row with any cell with a value other than None. So given your example you have Column A filled to row 11 so 'max_row' is 11.  If you want to check max row for a singular Column you'll need to check that column for last used cell individually.

Comment: You can do something like `last_row = [x.row for x in book_C3['Sheet1']['B'] if x.value is not None][-1]` which reads each cell in the selected Column and ends when if finds a cell with a None value. The returned value for 'last_row' would be 5.

Comment: You should probably search explicitly for the row based on content.